# relation between categories table and factories table Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, relation

I am wordking with CodeIgniter

I have a database with three tables called categories, factories and factorycategories

in my categories table i have the following rows:

```
idCategories
Categorie
idFactories
```

in my factories table i have the following rows:

```
idFactories
Factoryname
Postcode
Country
Telephone number
Email
Website
Profile
Adress
```

in my factorycategories i have the following rows:

```
id
idFactories
idCategories
Factorycategory
```

i want, when i click on a category seen in the image below that the factories show up that are located in that specific category.

Factories can be in more than one category.

So how do i make a relation between those tables to get those results when i click on a category.

[image: example]

How do i manage that with mysql database and phpmyadmin 2.8?

I searched on google but could not find something.

Comment: A factory can only belong to one category? In that case you should save the category ID in your factories table. What you have now is that each category belongs to *one* factory. That can't be right.

Comment: No i forgot to tell. i have another table in my db called factorycategories. with idCategories and idFactories. so maybe i have to do something with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, alter your DB-design...

```
table factories
-----------------
idFactories
idCategories (int) <---- add this field
Factoryname
Postcode
...
```

Then, query factories that belong to a specific category. Pass the `idCategories` with the link:

Create the links:

```
// sql to get all categories from the DB
$sql="SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY Categorie"    

// --- insert your code to pull the data from your DB here ---

// building your links on the left column
// assuming all rows from the sql above are in array $categories 
foreach ($categories as $cat) 
    echo '<a href="thispage.php?id='.$cat['idCategories'].'">'.$cat['Categories'].'</a>';
```

show factories according to clicked category...
quite at the beginning of your file:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && intval($_GET['id'])>0) 
    $id=intval($_GET['id']);
else $id=0;

if ($id>0) {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM factories WHERE idCategories=$id";
    // --- insert your code to pull the data from your DB here ---
    // store all the rows in array $factories
}
```

Outputting the factories:

```
if ($id>0) {
    foreach ($factories as $fac) {
       // code for echoing the data
    }
} else {
    echo "select a category on the left to show the factories...";
}
```

Ooops, I see you changed the relation between categories and factories in your question. Basically, the techniques are the same, only the sql would change.

Comment: Thanks very awesome. will try this. and never knew how to do this, the right way.

Comment: Yes but i'm very new to codeigniter so your code makes things clear. and that's good in the learning process

Comment: @KeesSonnema It should be added that both our solutions have nothing to do with CodeIgniter and is simply SQL and regular PHP code.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: true, I don't even know the tool

Comment: it looks a bit like your php michi. but it's not exactly right. so i think i have to wait to a codeigniter related answer

Comment: @KeesSonnema if there's an error in my code, let me know and I'll correct it. If it's CodeIgniter-specific, I'm afraid...

Comment: it is codeigniter-specific. Codeigniter works with MVC so i have to specify some thing in my model. in my controller and in my views. so it's a bit more complicated then your php code

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [`INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

```
SELECT
    fa.idFactories,
    fa.Factoryname,
    fa.Postcode,
    fa.Country,
    fa.Telephonenumber,
    fa.Email,
    fa.Website,
    fa.Profile,
    fa.Adress,
    fc.Factorycategory,
    ca.Categorie
FROM
    `factories` as `fa`
INNER JOIN
    `factorycategories` as `fc`
ON
    fa.idFactories = fc.idFactories
INNER JOIN
    `categories` as `ca`
ON
    ca.idCategories = fc.idCategories
WHERE
    ca.Categorie = 'MyCategory'
```

Comment: thanks will try this. when i have questions about this can i ask them to you also?

Comment: @KeesSonnema You should ask any questions to StackOverflow as a whole - we're all here to help individually, and most of us wish to go on SO at our own time. I can promise you that this query is very very basic, and anyone knowing MySQL on a decent level (most of the MySQL StackOverflow people) would be able to help you with it.